# How can I construct a generic type using properties from another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to be able to construct a type that accepts the type of another object and returns a different type based on certain properties in that object. This will be easier to explain in code:

```js
// these describe the type of inputs a UI would display
// and their returned values
// e.g. a colorHex UI control should return a string
type Inputs = {
  colorHex: string
  yearPicker: number
}

// colorHex | yearPicker
type InputTypes = keyof Inputs

// Describes an input. It has a type to define the UI and a label
type Input = {
  type: InputTypes
  label: string
}

// Describes a composition of inputs. Has an ID and an object with Inputs
type Composition = {
  id: string
  inputs: Record<string, Input>
}

// Describes a map of compositions
type Compositions = Record<string, Composition>

const comps: Compositions = {
  short: {
    id: 'short',
    inputs: {
      bgColor: {
        type: 'colorHex',
        label: 'BG Color',
      },
      year: {
        type: 'yearPicker',
        label: 'Count',
      },
    },
  },
}

// I want to recieve a composition and return a map of input key and the resulting input value type
type InputProps<T extends Composition> = {
  [P in keyof T['inputs']]: Inputs[T['inputs'][P]['type']]
}

// The input prop types for comps.short
type ShortProps = InputProps<typeof comps.short>

// What I want ShortProps to equal
type Expected = {
  bgColor: string
  year: number
}

// ultimately what I want to do with this
const someFn = (props: ShortProps) => {
    // props === { bgColor: string; year: number }
}

// this is correct
someFn({ bgColor: '#000', year: 2020 })

// this is incorrect and should result in a type error
someFn({ bgColor: 0, year: '2020' })
```

[Here is a playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsFMGdtAEzgYwE4EsBGCq4J4AOCA9gGagYB2hAruLKAIagCqAkqAO4m0A2iJBliE+TfACgQzKoLwY0oNNHC00VaIIBuTPrThSw0AHQBzY81AoSfEmgAS0AB5tO1quDQ3QsSLwFKKmpUlrCe1KYS4EQI7DT0jAC8oADeEqBWNnaOTgBcPuFUkRn40ExoAAoYKADW0Gj5VLQAtjhoEgC+EoaZtg7OoAA+oKXlVbX1UTGgcXTgACoxSaB1+OQz8Qzd0gAiqJg4jEwh1HMW7OCgkExHENPgJEjQZNS4MK4ygixiOHxTxBs5qBkmkMtFiPlZvRFsRYOlQD9oHx8mFMEVOtswHtYOhsHBLNZmoQSLAMOAMCQQutTgkLPYbjIZjtPoySFgAFbQFCXLhkyCAhL-BAAYRIRJJZIpIRB8IwiBRhWKlE2sHyACUuXZEAAeVERAA0AvAAD4MT1sbjDpZmkxCKB1oTiaTyZS4eCRWKnZLXcDQBrrGgdXqiobReLnVLTRJ3GFMkTVaAw16XVRlqCfH40OB8umMnL8gByXx2cAF-XwvMqnMVjKgLCmUV9au1lt3CGgAvWPo5Ms1luI5EdgBCAHFE1k0L3W6AOuXp6MGqk+7X3YWF+M6pO59OEUxfoXRbQPFPW7Oa2eMmeuj1OFxjpcHoEUBhoFoECxHRKUyzlKp1NbbXtCgaUuVYWTwQJYH4ckimVIEdD0AhiCFI0Ki8QhYG1eZQGccBoFkRgky-SNfXTABtCplRWaA1goeYyILEDYALABdFjIRVMj6MYlVWIoliGPdViWLNaR5neEDQEIdC23xMg7DjDDjGLLMUIAZUzcA0JIDDfShLT0Mw90HU9WBlM0qNpAAdWuS5b3vUANJLbTdMfaAAEdaF0FCAFEnGIblNFI+F60bOwFTRJUF0aFo2lEsBoIwG08L4fBuFsmZuAcx9EEeXkoAgSBhGjV1LlgMVoAAMWlUAAAppJ0hMnKzFzYAASmBY0lxbaQGt0xIBtSOsGwnCKIgAbhGMpFyaVp6hneLCuEShGADZRuQkcrmiqqhapSYawsXAsAGIAAZzrLKbynyAAmU67pnNrMSWxhluoNauUuY5BGLfhBGUKC+EuahLHdHC0C8dotp2vaDtG0BTsNaKOzuu6C0eoA). Notice that the last line does not give a type error when it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make sure that `comps` satisfies (or "matches") the type `Compositions`. Before this, you were overwriting the type information of the object by explicitly annotating it with `Compositions`. Currently in TS 4.8, we have to use a helper function for this:

```
function comp<C extends Compositions>(c: C) { return c }

const comps = comp({
  short: {
    id: 'short',
    inputs: {
      bgColor: {
        type: 'colorHex',
        label: 'BG Color',
      },
      year: {
        type: 'yearPicker',
        label: 'Count',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

However, in 4.9+, we can use `satisfies` keyword:

```
const comps = {
  short: {
    id: 'short',
    inputs: {
      bgColor: {
        type: 'colorHex',
        label: 'BG Color',
      },
      year: {
        type: 'yearPicker',
        label: 'Count',
      },
    },
  },
} satisfies Compositions;
```

Now you'll get an error on the last line, as desired.

[Playground (4.8-)](https://tsplay.dev/wOAQ6m)

[Playground (4.9+)](https://tsplay.dev/mL2VZw)

Comment: Aha, that's awesome, thank you! I had removed the explicit annotation in a previous iteration but then I kept getting a 2344 error because Typescript was not inferring `typeof comps.short` correctly. But either of those issues solves the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: I wasn't sure I'd fully understood what @caTS meant by "overwriting". [This dev.to article](https://dev.to/ayc0/typescript-49-satisfies-operator-1e4i) helped me understand why the question code didn't work but this answer's code does.

Comment: @JSmart523 The object you assign to `comps` inherently has a type, but if you add an explicit type annotation, you *lose* that type and now the type of the variable is the type you annotated it with. That's why I called it "overwriting" - you just overwrote the original type that was to be used with a new type.